# Session doesn't work in Laravel 5.2

Tags: session, laravel-5

I have a big problem with session in Laravel 5.2. My session doesn't set in some route.

Like this

```
Route::post('add','SiteController@add');
```

This is my `route.php`:

```
Route::get('admin','AdminController@index');
Route::resource('admin/product','ProcuctController');

Route::resource('admin/news','NewsController');
Route::resource('admin/category','CategoryController');
Route::get('session','SiteController@session');
Route::post('add','SiteController@add');
Route::get('/{title}','SiteController@show');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
      Route::get('session','SiteController@session');
      Route::post('add','SiteController@add');
});
```

My file shopping cms basket doesn't work. This is my `SiteController` function

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    if(session::has('cart'))
    {
          $cart=session::get('cart');

          if(array_key_exists($request->product_id,$cart))
          {
               $cart[$request->product_id]++;
          }
          else
          {
               $cart[$request->product_id]=1;
          }

          session::put('cart',$cart);
          //var_dump(session::get('cart'));
          print 'ok';
    }
    else
    {
          $cart=array();
          $cart[$request->product_id]=1;
          session::put('cart',$cart);
          var_dump(session::get('cart'));
    }
}
```

Every time that I click the buy button, condition doesn't return true

Comment: What version of Laravel 5.2 are you using? Version 5.2.27 now supports `web` middleware by default and declaring it again could cause you some headaches

Answer (score 0):

In your `router.php` you register `add` and `session` route twice. one is inside of `web` middleware and another is outside. Remove the outside one. so your router.php will look like

```
Route::get('admin','AdminController@index');
Route::resource('admin/product','ProcuctController');
Route::resource('admin/news','NewsController');
Route::resource('admin/category','CategoryController');
Route::get('/{title}','SiteController@show');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
      Route::get('session','SiteController@session');
      Route::post('add','SiteController@add');
});
```

And in your `SiteController` add this line in to top

```
use session;
```

Comment: i change route.php and i have a new problem  ` if(session::has('cart'))
       {
        ` never return true